# DropShadowing PlotStyle makes Plot trace pixelated on Cloud and Jupyter. Desktop too? Why? Fixes?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, rasterize

Both working on *Wolfram Engine + Jupyter Notebooks* or on *Wolfram Cloud*, I see pixelated traces and axes when using the new [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html)`->`[`DropShadowing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DropShadowing.html)`[]` style option on [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

Minimum example showing this difference:

```
Column[
    Map[
        Plot[
            AiryAi[x]
            , {x,-15,15}
            , PlotStyle -> #
        ] &
        , {Automatic, DropShadowing[]}
    ]
]
```

[image]

### Detail

[image]

There are other questions about pixelated 3D graphs or labels, but this seems a different problem.

## Questions

**꘏ Can anybody reproduce this on a *Mathematica* Front-end?**

**꘏ Why is this happening?**

**꘏ How to avoid the low quality raster?**

**꘏ Any workarounds?**

**꘏ Is this a bad choice of parameters or a bug?**

Comment: `DropShadowing` is implemented as a pixel shader, so the end result is always going to be an image.  The cloud is probably running at a lower dpi than your display.

Comment: @ihojnicki thanks for your comment. The shadow should be a raster, not the trace and axis. Also Wolfram Engine is local not the cloud, and in any case even if all is rasterized, it should happen at high enough resolution. Which it doesn't. I still want answers to the other closely related questions.

Comment: It is all or nothing.  i.e., it cannot be selective on which parts are rasterized.  I have no practical experience with Wolfram Engine + Jupyter, but I would start by altering the default value of `$ImageResolution`.

Comment: @ihojnicki not really one or the other, you can have both a raster shadow and a vector foreground easily with something like `f[gr_Graphics]:= Overlay[{GaussianFilter[Binarize[Rasterize[gr]],2], gr}]`. Also changing `$ImageResolution` doesn't make a difference. Did you try that ang got an improvement? It would be good to know if this problem can be reproduced elsewhere or not.

Comment: Your example `Plot` is going to generate a single `Graphics` expression, and it will be all or nothing inside of that.  I don't have a setup to try it, so the `$ImageResolution` suggestion was just an educated guess.  Your original example is fine in my desktop copy of Mathematica.

Comment: If you make your plot very big, ridiculously so, and then shrink it after it has been rasterized you may get a better result. This works on ordinary screens where the screen resolution controls the image resolution.  Only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but when I'm trying the following in Wolfram Desktop 13.2 for Mac, the first expression produces a small (15kb) pixelated image with a shadow. In comparison, the second produces a large (267kb), high-resolution image **without** a shadow:

```
Export["~/Downloads/test.png",
 Plot[{2 Sin[x] + x, 2 Cos[x] + x}, {x, 0, 15}, 
  PlotStyle -> DropShadowing[]]]

Export["~/Downloads/test2.png",
 Plot[{2 Sin[x] + x, 2 Cos[x] + x}, {x, 0, 15}, 
  PlotStyle -> DropShadowing[]],
 ImageResolution -> 1000]
```